# Is there an equivalent of __data_start__ in clang/lld?

Tags: windows, clang, symbols, built-in, msys2

For debugging purposes I need to programmatically access variables in my program using their addresses from the map file. This requires me to find the offset between compile-time addresses and runtime addresses.

I know GCC defines a special `__data_start__` symbol which can be used to find the start address of the data section at runtime:

```c
extern char __data_start__[];
int main()
{
    printf("data section starts at 0x%" PRIXPTR, __data_start__);
}
```

Is there an equivalent symbol in clang?